# I keep getting error message for str not callable closed

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a game but i keep getting this error when i ask the player if they want to defend or attack

```
defend_attack=input("Would you like to defend (you only take a quarter of the damage) or attack (you have a chance to stun opponent) ")
if defend_attack=="defend":
```

I've tried to put

```
defend_attack=str(input("Would you like to defend (you only take a quarter of the damage) or attack (you have a chance to stun opponent) "))
```

but it still doesn't work. and I keep getting this error message

```
defend_attack=input("Would you like to defend (you only take a quarter of the damage) or attack (you have a chance to stun opponent) ")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

this is the whole code

```
import time
import random

next_line=input("Press Enter to Start\n")
time.sleep(1)
print("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>")
time.sleep(3)
print("          Myth of the Faded Warrior and the Cursed Blade          ")
time.sleep(1)
print("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>")
print()
time.sleep(1)
user_name=input("Please enter your name: ")
difficulty=int(input("Please enter a difficulty:\n1 is easy\n2 is medium\n3 
is hard\n4 is insane\n"))
print()
print("Hello "+user_name+" and welcome to your journey!")
next_line=input("Press enter after each line to continue on ")
print()
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
print()
next_line=input("Your world used to be happy and full of life ")
next_line=input("The men, who go out to hunt their dinner for the night ")
next_line=input("The women, who stay at home and do the cleaning ")
next_line=input("And the children, who didn't have a worry in the world and 
just played all day ")
next_line=input("There were many tales of a warrior who drove himself crazy 
trying to get revenge on his nemesis ")
next_line=input("He finally found his nemesis and stabbed him in the back ")
next_line=input("He killed him with no honour ")
next_line=input("After his nemesis' death, the Gods put a curse on his blade 
and banished him from the Earth ")
next_line=input("Before he faded away he promised that he would come back 
and wreak havoc on the Gods ")
next_line=input("He did just that ")
next_line=input("He came back for revenge on the Gods")
next_line=input("It was not easy as those who wanted immense power seeked 
the Faded Warrior and tried to kill him ")
next_line=input("One succeeded and inherited the power of the Cursed Blade 
")
next_line=input("Those who inherited the Cursed Sword had the power to cut 
mountains in half ")
next_line=input("They had the power to fuse the soul of those they had 
killed to give them more power ")
next_line=input("They had the power to defeat the Gods if they were skilled 
enough ")
next_line=input("However the curse meant that those who inherit the blade, 
die after 3 months ")
next_line=input("The only way to relieve the curse was to kill the Gods ")
print()
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------")
print()
next_line=input("You are the next Faded Warrior ")
next_line=input("You kill the last Faded Warrior and pick up the Cursed 
Blade ")
next_line=input("You feel the power of a thousand souls run through your 
veins ")
next_line=input("The screams of a thousand souls rips a hole into the earth 
and monsters from the Underworld burst out ")
next_line=input("The monsters desperse and go into hiding ")
next_line=input("They seek only of your Cursed Blade ")
next_line=input("You hear voices saying to head to Shadowkeep ")
next_line=input("You know where this is all you have to do is head down the 
road ")
print()
if input("Do you want to head down the road to Shadowkeep? ")=="yes":
    next_line=input("You begin to go down the cobble road to Shadowkeep ")
else:
    next_line=input("I think you need to head down to Shadowkeep ")
print()
next_line=input("As you go down the cobble road you are startled by a Lycan 
")
health=100
next_line=input=("The Lycan seems ready to attack ")
while True:
    defend_attack=input("Would you like to defend (you only take a quarter 
    of the damage) or attack (you have a chance to stun opponent) ")
    if defend_attack=="defend":
        monster_hit=(random.randint(1,25)*difficulty//4)
        health=health-monster_hit
        next_line=input("You took "+str(monster_hit)+" damage ")
        next_line=input("You now have "+str(health)+" health ")
    else:
        monster_health=30*difficulty
        player_hit=random.randint(1,55)
        monster_health=monster_health-player_hit
        if monster_health<=0:
            next_line=input("You killed the Lycan ")
            break
        else:
            next_line=input("You hit the monster with "+str(player_hit)+" 
            damage ")
            next_line=input("The monster now has "+str(monster_health)+" 
            health ")
```

Comment: Thanks to use the correct tag. witch language for starting would be nice

Comment: This is for python

Comment: It seems at some point you've assigned a string to the name `input`, shadowing the built in function. We can't tell you where without a [mcve].

Comment: We need to see more of your code. Maybe you defined `str` somewhere before or `input` like said @jonrsharpe and what error did you get before using `str()` ?

Comment: okay thank you i've found that

Comment: I have been using the input so that when you press enter it goes on to the next line

Comment: That is besides the point @Richard. You seem to have assigned some string type variable named `input` which *hides* the function of `input()`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If not, try adding `print(repr(input))` right before the troublesome line. It should print `<built-in function input>`.

Comment: could it be this line `if input("Do you want to head down the road to Shadowkeep? ")=="yes":` @cricket_007

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: this is python 3 @tdelaney

Comment: Can you post your full code? That would be simplest at this point

Comment: Nope. That's an if statement... Where in the code have you done `input = <insert anything here>`?

Comment: nowhere? @cricket_007

Comment: I think the problem is that you used `input` as a variable name somewhere in your code, so that replaced the built-in function.

Comment: Something like `input = "some string"` would cause this error.

Comment: i have posted the whole code @EastonBornemeier

Comment: `next_line=input=("The Lycan seems ready to attack ")` You have an extra = sign after input

Comment: ok thank you i think that was what the problem was @EastonBornemeier

Comment: You can't have line breaks inside strings, unless you use triple-quoted strings. Is that a copying problem? When I tried to run your script I got errors for all those lines.

Comment: You should be aware that you do not have to write your code like that, see e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60366/32391 for how to define multiline blocks of text in a more readable way. You could also move that text out of the script (or out of the way) so you can focus on the actual code and maybe not make typos like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the full code has been posted:

`next_line=input=("The Lycan seems ready to attack ")`

You have an extra = sign after input

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3:
You most likely overwrote the input method with another variable. Change whatever variable that is named input to something else and retry!

Comment: How do you know this is Python2?

Comment: Fixed @cricket_007

Comment: i am using python3

Comment: @Barmar I suppose the python2 version would not, but the python3 version would due to the input referencing the variable instead of the input() function, making the str argument not callable to the variable. I have removed the python2 answer due to it not being relavent anymore